# Uploading a docker image to gcloud leads to service unavailable

Tags: dockerfile, containers, google-cloud-run

here is my docker file code:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir flask gunicorn flask_session firebase_admin python-dotenv
EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT=8080
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 wbvaa:app
```

I have tried locally building the image and testing it using these commands:

```
docker build -t test-image:latest .   
when run by: docker run -d -p 8080:8080 test-image:latest
```

this works fine, and I can see my application running on localhost:8080
but when trying to deploy this same image into gcloud it results 'service unavailable' error. The commands used for deployment:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/wbvaa-web/flask-fire  
gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/wbvaa-web/flask-fire
```

what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message? Also can you check these links on [troubleshooting Cloud Run issues](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting) and [known Cloud Run issues](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues)?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue. For Gcloud logs I found that the error was cloud run could not resolve a file path (of the firebase config json). File path was given as absolute path using os library and docker could resolve it. Somehow cloud run could not find the file.
Passed the config as object instead and it worked!

> Edit:
> Gcloud automatically ignores files in gitignore file